# How to configure launch.json for vscode to build main.go in root folder?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

The structure of my project is like this:

```
-cmd
 -debug
  - main.go
 -prod
  - main.go
-.env
```

If I use:
`go build .\cmd\debug\main.go`

The go compiler creates main.exe file in the root directory.
I can run this with .\main.exe and use my .env config file with
`os.Open(".env").`

But if I try launch my proj from vscode, with this launch.json:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Debug",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "./cmd/debug",
        }
    ]
```

Main.exe is generated in /cmd/debug and is not accessible by `os.Open(".env")`.
How do I configure vscode to build the project in the root directory?

I tried to find a similar question on Stackoverflow but had no luck.

Comment: Can you try with `go build .` instead? This way the executable file will exist in the root dir. I am suggesting that you should not have a different main.go file per environment. I am not sure what is your use case, but it is better to have just one main.go and load the env config from .env files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
The VS Code documentation describes this case.
The problem is solved by adding the "cwd" flag.
The documentation describes this flag as

> Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the
> program being debugged if a non-empty value is specified. The program
> folder is used as the working directory if cwd is omitted or empty.
> (Default: "")

src: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#launchjson-attributes

My actual launch.json file looks like this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Debug",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "./cmd/debugger",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    }
]
```